# Convert a string from a list into an integer

Tags: python, string, list, int, type-conversion

```
v=["there", 3, "9","hello",25]
x=values[1]+values.int[2]
#I want to make 9 an integer so I could get the sum of 3 and 9. Im getting an 
error
```

I already tried using the int function on values[2], and i am getting the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tigersoprano/Documents/text2.py", line 9, in 
    g=values[1]+values.int[2]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'int'

Answer (score 0):

First, your array is called `v`, not `values`
Second, the int function is `int()`

So:

```
v=["there", 3, "9","hello",25]
x=v[1]+int(v[2])
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> v=["there", 3, "9","hello",25]
>>> x=v[1]+int(v[2])
12
```

You get an 'AttributeError' because the 'list' type does not have an attribute called 'int', i.e., 'v.int' will not do anything. To cast a string to an integer, you can do the following

```
>>>int("9")
9
```